# Ubuntu 22.04 does not recognize Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet

Ubuntu 22.04 does not recognize Ethernet cable. lspci -k command shows below information.
Please help. I am windows user and playing with Ubuntu.

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
    Kernel modules: sky2
```

```
sudo lshw -C network 

 *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB]
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 11
       serial: 54:42:49:0e:5c:c0
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:25 memory:f2220000-f2223fff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:f2200000-f221ffff
```

Comment: Try another cable. They go bad, and never when you expect.

Comment: I used two cables and both the same

Comment: Try plugging the cable into a different port of your router or switch. Ports occasionally go bad.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong on the software side. Your ethernet interface hardware is detected properly by the operating system, and an appropriate kernel module (driver) is automatically loaded, `autonegotiation` is enabled, and `link=no`. Thus the hardware troubleshooting questions. The fault does not seem to be with Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe try https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=287759 at the very last comment where they disable the MSI for the driver and then remove and reload the sky2 driver to get Ethernet to see again.

Comment: I also tried with two port in the router. both didn't work. Also tried with two different cables. still no luck